# What is the difference between iPod touch and iPod touch 2nd generation?

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch

When submitting an app to the app store what is the real difference between iPod Touch and iPod Touch 2nd generation?

Comment: What happened to "programming related questions only"?

Comment: This is far more programming related than all the offtopic subjective questions out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first-gen iPod touch doesn't ship with iPhone OS 2.0, which is required to run App Store apps. End-users can purchase iPhone OS 2.0 for their first-gen iPod touch from Apple.

From an SDK perspective, I'm not sure what, if anything, has changed.

Comment: That's not really relevant, though, because you have to upgrade to 2.x to use the App Store. So everyone getting apps from the App Store is running 2.x.

Answer (score 20):

The following:

- Slightly thinner
- Built-in support for Nike+
- Volume bar
- External speaker
- Faster processor (533MHz vs 400MHz)
- Supports new headphones with the microphone and volume control (allowing you to use VOIP apps)

Answer (score 10):

Also, 2G iPod touches have microphone input capabilities and a built in speaker, as well as external volume buttons.

Also, the physical back of the device is curved, making it easier to hold.